# Aromatics from roasted chicken and sauce

Tags: chicken, roasting

I have been making tandoori chicken, and made it with the following [marinade](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/1853673/tandoori-roast-chicken). 
I place the chicken on top of aromatics consisting of carrots, celery, onions and yams.
When the chicken has been roasted, I am left with the juices and the aromatics.
I am not really sure what to do with these aromatics and how to serve them. For example, the large pieces of celery are pretty awkward, they are hard to chew. I am thinking of removing the yams, mash them and mix with cinnamon, but the rest I am not sure about.

How do you usually serve the aromatics that have been cooked under the roasted chicken? Also, can you leave the aromatics in the roasting pan while you make the sauce (or au jus)? Eventually, you would remove them of course and serve the aromatics separately.

Comment: How well did the vegetables come out?  I try to dice my veg (carrots potatos, onions and peppers, typically), so they're a reasonable size to just serve as-is once it's done (onions are quartered, so they don't cook down too far) ... but I've never cooked a coconut milk (or any milk) coated chicken over it, so don't know how that would affect things.

Comment: They come out great. I guess I could chop down the roasted celery before I serve it, before roasting would be preferable actually.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the vegetables and discard, they should have released all their "aromatics" to the gravy

You could press them in a chinois (fine meshed sieve) and extract more juices from them.

Pass all the juices through the chinois into a pot and reduce, and you could add a little bit of white wine to finish up the sauce to serve with the chicken.

When I roast chicken, I usually put potatoes, onions, garlic and carrots (and or other root vegetables) in the pan and they roast at the same time; most of the time, the onions are just too cooked to be served, so either I eat them myself, or just discard them.

Comment: Of the juices from the chicken, how much of it do you use for the sauce? I watched a Good Eats episode about roasted chicken and Alton Brown removed all of the juice and recommended using it for vinaigrette. Then he kept the aromatics in the roasting pan over two heaters, added broth and red vine until it reduced by half

Comment: I use all of it and add a little bit of white wine to the sauce; you could remove the juice put aside for a minute or so to have the fat float on top and remove it and put it back in and finish up the sauce.